# Global holomorphic sections of the line bundle associated to a nonprincipal divisor

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, not necessarily compact. Suppose $H$ is an analytic variety of codimension one that cannot be written as the zero set of a global holomorphic function; in other words, when $H$ is viewed as a nonzero divisor on $X$ it is nonprincipal.

There is a well-known holomorphic line bundle associated to $H$ denoted by $[H]$; this is given by taking local data $f_{\alpha}\in\mathcal{O}(U_{\alpha})$ of $H$ and associating to it the holomorphic line bundle which has transition function $g_{\alpha\beta}=f_{\alpha}/f_{\beta}$. The line bundle determined is independent of the local data of $H$ chosen.

Now it's not hard to see that the local data determines a global holomorphic section $s$ of $[H]$, since $f_{\alpha}=g_{\alpha\beta}f_{\beta}$. So $s^{-1}(0)=H$ for some global section. However, if $s'$ is *any* global holomorphic section of $[H]$, then it can be shown that the line bundle associated the divisor ${s'}^{-1}(0)$ is $[H]$. But two divisors determine the same line bundle if and only if they differ by a principal divisor, so ${s'}^{-1}(0)=H+(g)$, where $(g)$ is the divisor determined by a meromorphic function $g$ on $X$. (Here "+" denotes addition of divisors.)

My question is the following: Does this mean that every nontrivial global holomorphic section of [H] must contain $H$ as part of its zero locus? This seems awfully rigid --- am I making a mistake somewhere in my logic? I am rather new to divisors and line bundles, so I wouldn't be surprised if so. Any verification/debunking of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're a bit off, yes - it might help to consider a point in $\Bbb P^1$ to start. Then the line bundle is $\mathcal{O}(1)$, which has global sections $\operatorname{Span}(x,y)$, and for instance the divisor associated to $x$ is $[0:1]$ while for $y$ it's $[1:0]$.

Comment: As you mentioned the function $g$ is **meromorphic**, hence $(g)$ has zeroes and poles, so the equality $H' = H + (g)$ typically means that poles of $(g)$ cancel with $H$, while zeroes give $H'$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I realized I was thinking that $g$ 'meromorphic' meant that $g=f/h$ for some entire functions $f$ and $h$, but this is not necessarily the case. Your examples helped a lot!